# Handling Place (location) content type

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I have been using the `PyTelegramBotAPI` to handle `current location` with the content handler:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['location'])
```

I am able to get the latitude and longitude which is really great.

However, below the current location option, I can send the bot a place. (seems that it does not have `lat/lon` data but it is an address) Which content handler should I use to handle it? I tried finding some documentation on `https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/0.3.0/` but i cant find any :(

Many thanks if you could point me in the right direction :)
Attached a picture of the send current location/place option:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code where you're able to get latitude and longitude

Comment: @ShivamSahil Use message.location.latitude and message.location.longitude in your location message handler. :)

Comment: Okay I guess I had a different question. Let's say you do a command : `/LOCATEME` which is ideally a text but I want to fetch the location in that case and then send it back to user.

Comment: @ShivamSahil It is not possible to get location data from a text message. It has to be a location message type. An alternative is that after the user runs /LOCATEME the bot replies with a ReplyKeyboardButton that prompts the user to share their location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Use

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['venue'])
```

to handle places sent by users.